# Ajax jQuery , beginner question

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make an ajax call to grab session data to insert into my page after it's loaded like this

```
jQuery(function(){ // Add Answer

  jQuery(".add_answer").livequery('click',function(){
    var count = $(this).attr("alt");
    count++;
    var count1 = count-1;

    $.get('quiz/select', function(p_type){  // Ajax Call for Select Data

      $(this).parents('div:first').find('.a_type_'+count1+'').after('' + p_type + '');
      $(this).attr("alt", count);

    });
  });
});
```

The file i'm calling is found but its contents are not printed out by 'p_type'
and the `$(this).attr("alt", count);` part of the function is not executing

Note: I'm using CodeIgniter for my framework and jquery for js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your problem has to do with the scope of $(this).  Because you've got your ajax get function nested inside your livequery function, inside yet another anonymous function, I'd be willing to bet that $(this) is now refering to your $.get() call or something.

You need to cache $(this) as soon as possible at the point where you know it has the correct object selected:

```
jQuery(".add_answer").livequery('click',function()
{
    var add_answer = $(this);

    $.get(...)
    {
        add_answer.parents('div:first')...
    }
}
```

The above code *should* cache the add_answer element, but my livequery knowledge is a bit rusty.

Some recommendations on your code:

- Be consistent with the use of either jQuery() or $() shortcuts, they do the same thing.
- What's with the anonymous function surrounding the whole snippet? Is that just for a simplified example?  It should probably be replaced with a $(document).ready(function { ... });

Comment: Using $(function() { ... }) is equivalent to $(document).ready(function { ... });

Comment: you're right.  I've always found $(document).ready() to be clearer in its intentions.

Answer (score 0):

"this" is a special keyword in Javascript.
In your outer function it refers to .add_answer element.
And in your inner function it refers to window.

```
jQuery(".add_answer").livequery('click',function(){
  var self = this;
  // ...
  $.get('quiz/select', function(p_type){
    // ...
    $(self).attr("alt", count);
```